# Settings keep resetting after restart Oppo ColorOS

Tags: settings, factory-reset, 8.1-oreo, oppo-coloros

I have an Oppo R17 (Model CPH1879) running ColorOS V5.2.1 based on Android 8.1.0.

The problem is that every time I restart my device or if its battery runs out, some of my settings are reset to default. Not all my settings, I'll make it clear.

I realized that it is mainly

- The Auto-lock setting; keeps resetting to 15 seconds and I have to change it back to 2 minutes as it was,
- My alarm ringtone is reset to the default ringtone whereas I keep changing it to a custom file.

As of now I am not even sure if anything else changes besides these 2.

Since the ColorOS is still relatively new, searching on Google got me absolutely nowhere. Anyone come across this before or know how to fix this?